# How do you indent in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I can't figure out how to indent blocks of code in Google Colab. Pressing the tab does not indent. Right now, I'm resorting to pressing space twice for each line of code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply do the following.

1. Select the text you want to indent.
2. On Mac, press command + curly braces

For windows, Ctrl+curly braces would do the job

Comment: Awesome, worked for me. On windows, I pressed: ctrl + curly braces, instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Mark the lines and you'll see the different kinds of indentation.

Copy the original indent and paste it instead of the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

**Select the text you want to indent and then**
**On Windows:**
Press Ctrl + { for the left indent
Press Ctrl + } for the right indent

**On Mac**:
Press cmd + { for the left indent
Press cmd + } for the right indent

Answer (score 0):

I put `$\qquad$` at the beginning of paragraph. It comes from LateX and the $ makes Google Collab read the command \qquad. 
Hope that helps somebody.