# How do you indent in Google Collab - Windows

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I found that question on this site:
[How do you indent in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563584/how-do-you-indent-in-google-colab)
but it doesn't work for me since I am using Windows.
In the solution, I understand that I should press ctrl+curly braces.
But I couldn't make it
Which one should I press?
`ctrl+{`
or
`ctrl+}`
Could you please help me?

Comment: I found in setting of IDE you can press the button for showing the line for indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I found in setting of IDE you can press the button that says Show indentation guides to show the lines.
- Also pressing  (Ctrl + M + L) make IDE to show numbers of code line.